# Macro that rotates values

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm currently working on a spreadsheet with that includes multiple columns, with rows 10,11 and 12 in each column indicating whether you're number 1, 2 or 3, accordingly. More specifically, see the picture below.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/QezrzqW.png]

I need to build a macro that shifts the values each time it is used, so the cells in column A would change to A10=1, A11 and A12 =blank, column B to B12=3, B10 and B12 =blank, column C to C11=2, C10 and C12 =blank) etc. The macro would run until column AC is reached.

Is there any way this is possible? I have to change the values each day so that can become quite tedious for multiple columns.

Kind regards,
Thor

Comment: picture is blank ... also, if you don't show the coding efforts you have made, the question will most likely be ignored and closed.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear by your question as to how column A gets filled in, but something like this should do the trick:

```
Public Sub MoveRight()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim area As Range

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    With sh
        Set area = .Range(.Cells(10, 1), .Cells(12, 29))
    End With

    Dim r As Long, c As Long

    With area
        For c = .Columns.Count To 2 Step -1
            For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
                .Cells(r, c).Value = .Cells(r, c - 1).Value
            Next r
        Next c
        For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
            If .Cells(r, 4).Value = r Then
                .Cells(r, 1).Value = r
            Else
                .Cells(r, 1).Value = vbNullString
            End If
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but this does what you described ...

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub Simple()
Dim iloop As Integer

For iloop = 1 To 29
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, iloop) = 1 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, iloop) = ""
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(11, iloop) = 2
    Else
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(11, iloop) = 2 Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(11, iloop) = ""
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(12, iloop) = 3
        Else
            If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(12, iloop) = 3 Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(12, iloop) = ""
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, iloop) = 1
            End If
        End If
    End If

Next iloop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm. Had been using a similar code (my first post so I forgot to post it), without any luck.